# How to compare two column values incrementally and copy entire row if the cells in those columns meet a condition

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to compare two columns in one workbook and based on a certain condition copy the row where that condition is met to another workbook.

This is for a "database" I am working on. I have a Master sheet and then several versions of sub-masters that are catered specifically to certain individuals.

I have tried to some success by creating two different With statements and using a delete function on the sub-sheet but it is clunky and I'm not a fan of it. Please see the example code below.

```
Public Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim copyFrom As Range
Dim lRow As Long
Dim strSearch As String
Dim vrtSelectedItem As Variant

Set wb1 = Application.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\myfolder\Desktop\Excel Master Test\ROLE BASED TRACKER DRAFT.xlsx")
Set ws1 = wb1.Worksheets("Master")

Set wb2 = ThisWorkbook
Set ws2 = wb2.Worksheets("Sheet1")

'~~> Specifies which resources info. you are retrieving
strSearch = "117"
ws2.Cells.Clear

'~~> Copying the header information and formatting.
ws1.Range("1:1").Copy
ws2.Range("1:1").PasteSpecial

With ws1

    '~~> Remove any filters
    .AutoFilterMode = False

    lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    With .Range("L1:L" & lRow)
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=strSearch
         Set copyFrom = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow
    End With

    .AutoFilterMode = False

End With

'~~> Destination File

With ws2
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Rows) <> 0 Then
        lRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                      After:=.Range("A1"), _
                      Lookat:=xlPart, _
                      LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                      SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                      SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                      MatchCase:=False).Row + 1
    Else
        lRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    End If
    copyFrom.Copy .Rows(lRow)
End With

With ws2
        '~~> Remove any filters
    .AutoFilterMode = False

    lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    With .Range("AD1:AD" & lRow)
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=strSearch
        .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    End With

    .AutoFilterMode = False

End With

With ws1

    '~~> Remove any filters
    .AutoFilterMode = False

    lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    With .Range("AD1:AD" & lRow)
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=strSearch
         Set copyFrom = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow
    End With

    .AutoFilterMode = False

End With

'~~> Destination File

With ws2
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Rows) <> 0 Then
        lRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                      After:=.Range("A1"), _
                      Lookat:=xlPart, _
                      LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                      SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                      SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                      MatchCase:=False).Row + 1
    Else
        lRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    End If
    copyFrom.Copy .Rows(lRow)
End With

With ws2.Sort
    .SetRange Range("A2:A12000")
    .Header = xlNo
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With

wb1.Save
wb1.Close
wb2.Save

End Sub
```

This is the code that I am trying to get work. **I keep getting a Type Mismatch error on my cell comparison lines**. '' `If ws1.Range("AD1:AD" & lRow) <> ws1.Range("L1:L" & lRow) Then` ''

```
Public Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim copyFrom As Range
Dim lRow As Long
Dim strSearch As String
Dim vrtSelectedItem As Variant

Set wb1 = Application.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\myfolder\Desktop\Excel Master Test\ROLE BASED TRACKER DRAFT.xlsx")
Set ws1 = wb1.Worksheets("Master")

Set wb2 = ThisWorkbook
Set ws2 = wb2.Worksheets("Sheet1")

'~~> Specifies which resources info. you are retrieving
strSearch = "117"
ws2.Cells.Clear

'~~> Copying the header information and formatting.
ws1.Range("1:1").Copy
ws2.Range("1:1").PasteSpecial

With ws1

    '~~> Remove any filters
    .AutoFilterMode = False

    lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    If ws1.Range("AD1:AD" & lRow) <> ws1.Range("L1:L" & lRow) Then

        With .Range("AD1:AD" & lRow)
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=strSearch
            Set copyFrom = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow
        End With

        .AutoFilterMode = False

    End If

End With

'~~> Destination File

With ws2
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Rows) <> 0 Then
        lRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                      After:=.Range("A1"), _
                      Lookat:=xlPart, _
                      LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                      SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                      SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                      MatchCase:=False).Row + 1
    Else
        lRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    End If
    copyFrom.Copy .Rows(lRow)
End With

With ws1

    '~~> Remove any filters
    .AutoFilterMode = False

    lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    If ws1.Range("AD1:AD" & lRow) = ws1.Range("L1:L" & lRow) Then

        With .Range("L1:L" & lRow)
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=strSearch
            Set copyFrom = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow
        End With

        .AutoFilterMode = False

    End If

End With

'~~> Destination File

With ws2
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Rows) <> 0 Then
        lRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                      After:=.Range("A1"), _
                      Lookat:=xlPart, _
                      LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                      SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                      SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                      MatchCase:=False).Row + 1
    Else
        lRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    End If
    copyFrom.Copy .Rows(lRow)
End With


With ws2.Sort
    .SetRange Range("A2:A12000")
    .Header = xlNo
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With

wb1.Save
wb1.Close
' wb2.Save

End Sub
```

Comment: You cannot do this: " If ws1.Range("AD1:AD" & lRow) <> ws1.Range("L1:L" & lRow) Then", you have to loop through the ranges and compare the values of each cell.

Comment: Okay, I misunderstood what I was typing

Comment: I was hoping to stay away from looping through my sheet of 10,000 rows which is why I was using the AutoFilter method. Time to find another solution!

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to thank everyone who helped. I am going to just stick with my initial solution of filter, copy, paste, filter, delete, filter, copy, paste, sort.

See my first code block for what I am talking about. Cheers.